# Regular expression - specific text inside brackets

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, regex

I am writing a node.js app that does scraping.
I need to select from a string:

```
[
  [17,"EUR",17.03,"False",""],
  [20,"EUR",20.04,"False",""],
  [23,"EUR",23.05,"False",""]
],
[
  [1500,"RUB",1524.2,"False",""],
  [1800,"RUB",1793.9,"False",""],
  [2100,"RUB",2062.99,"False",""]
]
```

only [..."EUR"...] arrays but I am confused with regexp.

Tried `\[(\\bEUR)?\]` and similar ones.
How I should correct it? Thanks

UPD: to be more specific - return

```
[20,"EUR",20.04,"False",""]
```

not

```
[2100,"RUB",2062.99,"False",""]
```

and there are many confusing `[]` brackets

Comment: If it's an array, why not using an array function like `filter` or `find` instead?

Comment: okay. But filter function anyway requires a pattern

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use `Array.filter` instead of using RegEx. It will be more straightforward and easily understandable to use just that.

EDIT: Since currencies are grouped together, you may check just the first array:

```
Array.filter(x => x[0].includes("EUR"));
```

Comment: good idea. But it cuts all inside the array. I just need to leave arrays with EUR (see above)

Comment: @IliaSoloveychik are all currencies grouped together? If that's the case, you can check just the first array instead - `Array.filter(x => x[0].includes("EUR"));` - then destructure the return array afterwards if needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` and `some`:

```js
const bla = [
  [17, "EUR", 17.03, "False", ""],
  [20, "EUR", 20.04, "False", ""],
  [23, "EUR", 23.05, "False", ""],
  [1500, "RUB", 1524.2, "False", ""],
  [1800, "RUB", 1793.9, "False", ""],
  [2100, "RUB", 2062.99, "False", ""],
];

const out = bla.filter(el => el.some(nEl => nEl === 'EUR'));
console.log(out);
```